# Problemas al redirigir http a https en slackware

Tags: linux, apache, http, ssl, https

estoy creando una pagina web con slackware 15 con un servidor local en apache, y estoy    redirigiendo la pagina con el protoclo de http a https con un certifcado ssl creado con el comando:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out apache-certificate.crt -keyout apache.key
```

para redirigirlo cree los host virtuales en el archivo /etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf pero ocurre el problema que se redirigue pero no muestra la pagina en el navegador y el certificado ssl tampoco, la configuracion que tengo es la siguiente:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName manu2001.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin root@localhost
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/ejemplo.com/public_html"
  ServerName manu2001.com
  ServerAlias www.jos-ejemplo.com
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
  <directory "/var/www/ejemplo.com/public_html">
  Require all granted
  </directory>
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

La pagina si se muestra correctamente sin redirigirla a https y solo teniendo la configuracion basica.

en el navegador aparece asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya probaste en la configuraciones de DNS que esten los registro A hacia la ip del servidor, también verifica si tu servidor tiene abierto los puertos 80 y 443

Comment: Si era el puerto, el puerto 443 estaba cerrado lo comprobé con el comando nc -zv {IP} {PUERTO}